# Order frames in a grid in Figma

Tags: layout, figma

I have about 3000 frames with icons currently on my Figma page. It looks like this:
[image]

I want to have them ordered in a grid. So instead of this:

```
X
X
X
X
```

I want it to become this:

```
X X
X X
```

Auto-layout unfortunately only works in one direction.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: There's a plugin for Figma called [AutoGrid](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/817474150404549708/AutoGrid). Take a look and see if it will work for you. Note: I have no affiliation with figma or the plugin developers.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks, but it seems that plugin gets stuck with that many frames

Answer (score 1):

Yay, Figma has heard you.

[image]

You can use the *new* **wrap** function to do it. Just make sure that your Frame 1 is fixed width and wide enough to hold `X X`